# JavaScript Slideshow Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I am programming a very simple JavaScript slideshow and it isn't working. I do not want jQuery. This code displays the first image after 5 seconds, however does not cycle through the rest of the images. The full code is as follows, I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript Slideshow</title>
        <style>
        #slider > img { display: none }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="slider">
            <img src="img1.png">
            <img src="img2.png">
            <img src="img3.png">
            <img src="img4.png">
            <img src="img5.png">
        </div>
        <script>
            var s = document.getElementById("slider").getElementsByTagName("img");
            var c = s.length;
            setInterval(function() {
                s[(s.length++) % c].style.display="block";
            }, 5000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with `(s.length++) % c`

Comment: I stole it from another slideshow of mine.
var image = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png", "img4.png", "img5.png"];
var count = image.length;
setInterval(function() {
 document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", image[(image.length++) % count]);
}, 5000);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several errors in it.

1. You're trying to increment the array length, and modulo it by the counter. I bet you wanted to do that the other way around:

   `s[c % (s.length)].style.display="";`
2. You're not hiding the images already cycled through, so your cycle will only display once.

   ```
       var s = document.getElementById("slider").getElementsByTagName("img");
       var c = s.length;
       setInterval(function() {
           s[c % s.length].style.display="";
           s[(++c) % s.length].style.display="block";
       }, 5000);
   ```